# Rails association with two foreign keys?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, has-one

I am very new to Rails and I could not find a similar situation through searching. I have two existing tables `event` and `data`:

`event` has many, many columns:

```
+-------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field             | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| sid               | int(10) unsigned     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| cid               | int(10) unsigned     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| signature         | varchar(255)         | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| src_ip            | int(10) unsigned     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| dst_ip            | int(10) unsigned     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| ...               | ...                  | ...  | ... | ...     |       |
| etc               |                      |      |     |         |       |
+-------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

`data` has only three:

```
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| sid          | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| cid          | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| data_payload | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

My models:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :payload, :foreign_key => 'cid', :primary_key => 'cid'
  self.table_name = "event";
  [more stuff]
end

class Payload < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  self.table_name = "data";
end
```

Using the has_one relationship, I can perform a query such as:

`Event.limit(5).offset(90000).each do |e|`

and then loop through and call `e.payload` for each iteration and this would perform a query such as:

```
SELECT  `data`.* FROM `data`  WHERE `data`.`cid` = 90001 LIMIT 1
```

But this is clearly not the right way to do so. I feel like I am making an ass out of myself for typing it out here.

I think my ideal query would be something like:

```
SELECT `event`.`cid`, `event`.`sid`, `event`.`signature`, `data`.`data_payload` 
FROM `event`, `data` 
WHERE `event`.`sid` = `data`.`sid` AND 
      `event`.`cid` = `data`.`cid` AND
      `event`.`signature` LIKE 'example_signature'
```

Is there a way to do this all in one query with a proper Rails association? Just thinking about the hoops I am going to have to go through to pass the eventual ActiveRecord/hash object to my view makes me think I am doing this in a really roundabout way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean, that it should not be firing a new `SELECT` query with each pass?

You can optimize this with the `includes()` directive like this:

```
events = Event.includes(:payload).where('signature LIKE ?', 'example_signature')
events.each do |event|
  puts e.payload.data_payload
end
```

That would load all your data in 2 queries, one for all the events, and another for all the payloads that have a foreign key back to your events:

```
Event Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "event".* FROM "event"  WHERE (signature LIKE 'example_signature')
Payload Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "data".* FROM "data"  WHERE "data"."cid" IN (2,4,5,6,7)
```

**Edit**:

Your comments seem to indicate that performance is a top concern for this (probably because the tables are huge), so I think you were pretty close already. I would suggest selecting just the columns you need (since the events table has many of them), and using and SQL `JOIN` to add the other table's contents to query directly (since there is a one-to-one mapping of event to payload)

This will do that:

```
Event.
  select('event.cid, event.sid, event.signature, data.cid, data.sid, data.data_payload').
  joins(:payload).
  where('signature LIKE ?', 'example_signature').each do |event|
  puts event.data_payload
end
# SELECT event.cid, event.sid, event.signature, data.cid, data.sid, data.data_payload FROM "event" INNER JOIN "data" ON "data"."cid" = "event"."cid" WHERE (signature LIKE 'example_signature')
```

This will also preserve your Event object, so you can call other methods on it, but *ONLY* if they don't depend on attributes you excluded in the `select()` clause.

If you don't need any other methods from your Event object, and just want results as quickly as possible, then you could run a raw query with:

```
sanitized_str = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote('example_signature')
result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(
  "SELECT event.cid, event.sid, event.signature, data.cid, data.sid, data.data_payload
   FROM event
   INNER JOIN data ON data.cid = event.cid
   WHERE (signature LIKE #{sanitized_str});"
)
# => [{"cid"=>2, "sid"=>1, "signature"=>"example_signature", "data_payload"=>"Hello world!", 0=>2, 1=>1, 2=>"example_signature", 3=>2, 4=>1, 5=>"Hello world!"}]
```

This will return an array of records with each record as a plain-old ruby hash. Event objects won't be built in-memory, saving a lot of overhead.

Comment: This seemed like a great idea, so I decided to give it a quick test:

edit: oops, way too many characters. But this is the result: **Payload Load (264023.1ms)** I am not entirely sure why it is so ridiculously slow.

Comment: To answer your original question ("Do you mean..") however, my question is more how can I have the WHERE clause include both `event.cid = data.sid AND event.sid = data.sid` because that seems to be much, much quicker in my MySQL tests.

Comment: @aplewandowski I've updated my answer to hopefully address some of your concerns. Let me know how it goes!

Comment: I was worried I wasn't doing it the rails or ruby "way" hard-coding so much SQL. I believe your two example queries will probably help me on my way. Thanks very much for taking a look.

Comment: Both of those examples are very rare in most Rails code I've seen. ActiveRecord is great because you can hang a great deal of functionality off of a model record object, but in certain situations like this, it can really pay off to do without those rich objects and get closer to the metal.